# Windows 7 Touch Screen Delay

Tags: c#, touch

Hi I've got a program that has a label that I need to hold for 2.5 secs. I Know how to do it but the touchscreen I am using has a press and hold feature that i disabled but it still has a several second delay. Several places I looked at say its a windows problem Can anyone help??

```
    `private void ltitellongpress(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 2500;
        _timer.Tick += Do_Something;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void Do_Something(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }

    private void ltitle_mouseup(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer = null;
    }
```

Comment: The issue is probably with the touchscreen driver. Your code does not have any kind of delay in it.

Comment: that is what  i thot it was but others tell me i can remove the delay with c# i don't know how tho

Comment: they say its a windows 7 issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do this by eliminating the delay in the driver itself